# Where can I find the official response to Austria from Serbia in the July Crisis?

Tags: world-war-one, austria-hungary

I am asking if it still exists, and if it does, if there is a photograph of the document and if this document is in a current museum exhibition. I am referring to the Serbian response to the "ultimatum" sent by Austria, which was redacted at to some point by Berchtold.

Answer (score 6):

[The Serbian Response to the Austro-Hungarian Ultimatum](https://www.bl.uk/collection-items/austrohungarian-ultimatum-to-serbia-and-serbian-response):

- [French original](https://wwi.lib.byu.edu/index.php/The_Serbian_Response_to_the_Austro-Hungarian_Ultimatum_(French_original))
- [English translation](https://wwi.lib.byu.edu/index.php/The_Serbian_Response_to_the_Austro-Hungarian_Ultimatum_(English_translation))

Comment: The "french original" is full of mispellings.

Comment: @Bregalad - It would have been amusing if they'd tried to translate the French misspellings into English misspellings.